# paging with scrollview, not able to adjust image in imageview

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am implementing the paging in scroll view. Scroll view having size (259,263) and images of size (741, 723). SO far i am able to get little bit success. Images are so big that it over lap each other. I am not able to adjust image size on image view.  Here is my code:

```
- (void)setupPage
{
 NSMutableArray *imageArray= [[NSMutableArray
alloc]initWithObjects:@"female.png",@"male.png",nil];

int nimages;

CGFloat cx = 0;
for (nimages = 0; nimages<[imageArray count]; nimages++)
{ 
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageArray objectAtIndex:nimages]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    if (image == nil)
            {
        break;
    }

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.size.height = image.size.height;
    rect.size.width = image.size.width;
    rect.origin.x = ((scrollView.frame.size.width - image.size.width) / 2) + cx;
    rect.origin.y = ((scrollView.frame.size.height - image.size.height) / 2);

    imageView.frame = rect;

    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    cx += scrollView.frame.size.width;
}

self.pageControl.numberOfPages = nimages;
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, [scrollView bounds].size.height)];
 }

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView
{
if (pageControlIsChangingPage)
{
    return;
}
CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width/2;
int page = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth/2 ) / pageWidth) + 1;
pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

i get my solution by giving static size to my image view

here is my code
      NSUInteger nimages;

```
for (nimages = 1; nimages <= [imageArray count]; nimages++)
{

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageArray 
   objectAtIndex:nimages-1]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    if (image == nil)
    {
        break;
    }


    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
    rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
    imageView.frame = rect;

       imageView.tag = nimages;   
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

}

UIImageView *view = nil;
NSArray *subviews = [scrollView subviews];

// reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
for (view in subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
        view.frame = frame;

        curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
    }
}

// set the content size so it can be scrollable
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(([imageArray count] * kScrollObjWidth), [scrollView 
  bounds].size.height)];
```

Comment: @Do you want to show images in scroll view fully in or center.

Comment: @Gypsa in center. Its showing beacuse i cant able to adjust image of large size in image view i guess.

Comment: do you want to show your images in any predefined frame like you are saying it should come in center.

Comment: no no see the code how am i giving the size to image view CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.size.height = image.size.height;
    rect.size.width = image.size.width;
    rect.origin.x = ((scrollView.frame.size.width - image.size.width) / 2) + cx;
    rect.origin.y = ((scrollView.frame.size.height - image.size.height) / 2);

Comment: only i am unable to adjust image in image view along with width of page